# Add to Cart Function - No Method Error (undefined method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi guys so i am attempting a "add to cart function". I keep receiving "cart undefined method or variable" error and i can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong.

Here's my cart.rb model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutors

  def add_tutor(tutor_id)
    tutor = Tutor.where('tutor_id = ?', tutor_id)
    if tutor
      Cart.tutors << tutor
    end
    save
  end
end
```

Here's my carts_controller.rb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @cart = current_cart
  end

  def add_to_cart
    current_cart.add_tutor(params[:tutor_id])
    redirect_to tutors_path
  end

end
```

methods defined in application_controller.rb

```
def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end
```

code in routes.rb for the button

```
post '/add_to_cart/:tutor_id' => 'carts#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'
```

and the code for the button to add to cart

```
<%= button_to "Shortlist Tutor", add_to_cart_path(:tutor_id => :tutor_id), :method => :post %>
```

Whenever i try the "Shortlist Tutor" button, i receive a NoMethodError in CartsController#add_to_cart, undefined method `tutors' for Cart(id: integer):Class

and the highlighted error is on the cart.rb model file and the line being

```
Cart.tutors << tutor
```

Any help regarding this error is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Cart.tutors << tutor` Cart is a class. To add `tutors` to `Cart`, `Cart` must be an object. In your case `current_cart` is an object but Cart is class. so replace Cart in cart.rb with self as shown below

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutors

  def add_tutor(tutor_id)
    tutor = Tutor.where('tutor_id = ?', tutor_id)
    if tutor
      self.tutors << tutor
    end
    save
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for that solution! yes it does seem like it solved my issue because i'm no longer getting the undefined method error now! thank you once again!

The error now has become SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tutor_id: SELECT "tutors".* FROM "tutors" WHERE (tutor_id = '2')

Comment: It is because u dont have column called tutor_id in Tutor. So replace "tutor = Tutor.where('tutor_id = ?', tutor_id)"  by  "tutor = Tutor.find(tutor_id)". Now if it says record not found than that means no tutor record is present with id as tutor_id

Comment: Its working like a charm now! i can't thank you enough for helping me with this! Cheers to you :)